# Form Sheet of Modal Segue doesn't work with storyBoard

Tags: ios, ios8, storyboard, segue

i am trying to present a view modally using the Model "Form Sheet". Surprisingly, all subviews that i add via storyboard are not shown , but when i try to create them using code (on viewDidload for example) these views are shown in the screen.
Also when i have changed the model to "Full Screen" the views are shown in this case too.
This is an iPad project being developed under iOS 8 version.

please can you give me you suggestion to resolve the issue.

**EDIT**

[image]
[image]
[image]
Here is some screenshots which shows how i made my transition using storyboard:
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: do you mean action sheet by form sheet ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli no, it is form sheet.

Comment: did you get any solution? I am facing the same problem?

Comment: Have u found solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Modal Segue in the storyboard and make sure that you embed the view controller in the navigation controller. And perform segue whenever you need to:

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];

Also make sure of the content size of the form sheet and place the sub views in correct position.

Comment: this is what i made , but strangely content is not loaded .

Comment: Did you add segue to the view controller or to some other view in the view controller?

Comment: to the view controller, and i as described, when i present it in Full Screen instead of form sheet everything is OK.